# NSDate() - Playground vs. Swift Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I noticed that when I am in a Swift playground, a call to NSDate() generates a date with this format:

```
< date time AM|PM >
```

However, inside xcode/app, NSDate() generates a date with this format

```
< date time UTC >
```

I am not clear why there is such a difference? How can I force xcode to always generate NSDate as `< date time AM|PM >`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSDate` is used to represent a point in time. It does not have any notion of format.
What you want to use to print the content of an `NSDate` is `NSDateFormatter`

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
```

Answer (score 5):

`NSDate` doesen't have any concept of a time zone per se. From the docs

> The sole primitive method of NSDate, timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate,
>   provides the basis for all the other methods in the NSDate interface.
>   This method returns a time value relative to an absolute reference
>   date—00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001.

In the playground if you just write `let date = NSDate()` its doing some kind of date formatting on its own (which is interesting but should not be expected). If you `print(date)` if will show you what the date actually contains.

[image]

If you want to format dates inside of your app you should look at using the `NSDateFormatter` class.